# Cleanest way to bind a Button's visibility to the contents of two textboxes

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `Button` within my app whose "enabledness" I have bound to whether a `TextBox` is empty as so:

```
<Button Content="Go" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Text, 
                    Converter={StaticResource EnableIfStringNotEmptyDataSource}, 
                    ElementName=MyTextbox}"/>
```

(implementation of `EnableIfStringNotEmptyDataSource` omitted for brevity).

This automatically changes the state when the `TextBox`'s text changes.

What would be the most elegant way of binding a property in the same manner to whether **two** textboxes are both empty or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** For silverlight this is probably the cleanest it gets:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TB1Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding TB2Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Content="Lorem Ipsum" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnabled}"/>
```

```
private string _TB1Text;
public string TB1Text
{
    get { return _TB1Text; }
    set
    {
        if (_TB1Text != value)
        {
            _TB1Text = value;
            PropertyChanged.Notify(() => this.TB1Text);
            PropertyChanged.Notify(() => this.ButtonIsEnabled);
        }
    }
}

private string _TB2Text;
public string TB2Text
{
    get { return _TB2Text; }
    set
    {
        if (_TB2Text != value)
        {
            _TB2Text = value;
            PropertyChanged.Notify(() => this.TB2Text);
            PropertyChanged.Notify(() => this.ButtonIsEnabled);
        }
    }
}

public bool ButtonIsEnabled
{
    get { return !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TB1Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(TB2Text)); }
}
```

(*`PropertyChanged.Notify` is just an extension method which raises the event without the need to pass around strings*)

---

Would not use a binding but a `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<TextBox Name="tb1"/>
<TextBox Name="tb2"/>
<Button Content="Lorem Ipsum">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb1}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/> 
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb2}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/> 
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

By the way, you do not need a converter for your one TextBox case:

```
<Button Content="Lorem Ipsum" IsEnabled="{Binding Text.Length,
                                                  ElementName=MyTextBox}"/>
```

Comment: Nice answer and thanks for the heads-up about my single `TextBox` case, but seems `Style.Triggers` is a no-go for WP7 :-(

Comment: @funkybro: Added the method that i would probbably use with Silverlight restrictions.

Comment: nice, I guess WP7 will get Silverlight 4 eventually!

Comment: Does it matter if `sys` is mapped to System (mscorlib) or System (System)? I have it mapped to mscorlib and it works, but I am curious.

Comment: @Hydronium: Yes, of course it does. The System namespace in the mscorlib is what you want because it contains the types that you need, you can look at the two assemblies in VS to see what types they contain.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why people insist on writing code when this is doable completely in XAML.  To do this, you'll need the Blend SDK (for Windows Phone or .NET 4, whichever platform you're targeting).  Add references to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll.  Then you just need to declare change the button's enabled state (`ChangePropertyAction`) whenever the text changes (`EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged"`).  You'll need two changes: one to enable the button when both TextBoxes have text and another to disable the button when one TextBox lacks text.  The only "trick" here is declaring an empty string resource so you have something against which you can compare the text values.

The XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.MainPage">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <System:String x:Key="EmptyString"></System:String>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                            <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                            </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" PropertyName="IsEnabled"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                            <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}" Operator="NotEqual" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox2}" Operator="NotEqual" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                            </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Grid.Row="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                            <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox2}" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                            </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" PropertyName="IsEnabled"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                            <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}" Operator="NotEqual" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox2}" Operator="NotEqual" RightOperand="{StaticResource EmptyString}"/>
                            </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
        <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Row="2" Content="Go" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Edit: This will work in WPF, Silverlight, and WP7 (and probably WinRT when it's released).  For WP7, you need Windows Phone SDK 7.1 which includes the Expression Blend SDK for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm tempted to give -1 for attitude.  I don't think it's a case of people *"insisting on writing code rather than XAML"* as you put it.  I consider XAML such as that which you have supplied (while it probably can be generated quite easily by a Blend expert), to be rather impenetrable to the human eye and could certainly not be written by hand; as such I consider that to be quite inelegant.  Also as a WP7 beginner I have found learning all the XAML syntax which Blend *doesn't* do for you to be one of the hardest hurdles to overcome.

Comment: Learning XAML is definitely one of the longer roads within .NET and I feel for you as you're just starting out.  XAML is a verbose language hence your feeling that the above solution is inelegant.  After all, it is quite a bit of XAML.  However, that's also it's strength: your entire user interface is declarative.  Everything you need to know is right there in that file in a declarative format.  I'd highly recommend taking the time to learn Blend.  It will only benefit you going forward.

Comment: You don't need an empty string resource, see the MultiDataTrigger part of my answer. Also i second that notion about attitude, further event triggers are hardly declarative, they are just as imperative as code behind.

Comment: I haven't heard about ConditionalExpression before. Thank you for that example. Very useful.

Comment: The empty string resource is required outside of WPF. Event triggers are declarative in that they're part of the XAML; all XAML gets compiled down to imperative .NET code. I have a strong point of view that all user interactions should exist in XAML instead of being split into XAML + code; I won't apologize for enforcing a separation between architectural layers.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that you have bound your TextBoxs each to a class string property.
In which case you then bind the button enable to a boolean property that performs the test on the text properties in the getter and returns true/false accordingly.

e.g. in your ViewModel (assuming MVVM with Silverlight)

```
public class ViewModel
{
//note INotifyPropertyChanged functionality ommitted for brevity.
public string TextBox1{get;set;}
public string TextBox2{get;set;}

public bool EnableButton
{
  get{ return (!(TextBox1.IsNullOrEmpty() || TextBox2.IsNullOrEmpty());
}
}
```

Comment: The property won't change as the `TextBox`es' values change without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I was looking for a cleaner solution, ideally one which binds directly to the `TextBox`.